# Child form is not blinking when click on parent window

Tags: c#, winforms, wndproc

I'm developing a custom form that provides more options to customize the appearance of the form.

For that I have derived the class from `System.Windows.Forms.Form` class and overridden the `WndProc(ref Message m)` method.

I have processed the required window messages (`WM_NCPAINT`, `WM_NCCALCSIZE`, etc) to customize the form.

I have show the form customform by following code to show the child form through the button click.

```
CustomForm form = new CustomForm();
form.ShowDialog();
```

while clicking the parent form the childform is not flickering.But in the microsoft form the flickering occurs.

I have handled the window message WM_NCCALCSIZE to specify the client area size of my form as given below.

```
void On_WM_NcCalcSize(ref Message m)
 {
    rect.Top += borderThickness + titleBarHeight;
    rect.Left += borderThickness;
    rect.Right -= borderThickness;
    rect.Bottom -= borderThickness;
    m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(rect, m.LParam, true);
 }
```

And I have handled the WM_NCPAINT to draw the custom titlebar and border and other customization.

I have also handled the On_Wm_NcActivate through the following code.

```
 private void On_Wm_NcActivate(ref Message m)
        {
            if (!this.IsMdiContainer)
                NativeMethods.LockWindowUpdate(this.Handle);
            base.WndProc(ref m);
            NativeMethods.LockWindowUpdate(IntPtr.Zero);
            if (Style != null)
            {
                var msg = new Message();
                msg.Msg = WindowMessages.WM_NCPAINT;
                msg.HWnd = m.HWnd;
                msg.WParam = (IntPtr)1;
                msg.LParam = (IntPtr)0;
                On_Wm_NcPaint(ref msg);
            }
       }
```

I have no idea where i have gone wrong.So please give me the suggestion

Comment: The OS flashes the window by sending multiple WM_NCACTIVATE messages, flipping the WParam back-and-forth.  You are not using it.

Comment: Thank you Hans Passant,Please If possible can you give me the code?

Comment: Hi Hans Passant,I have tried as you said but it not flickers.Can I get the small code from you and reason why the flickers is not happening...

Answer (score 0):

you should set the "form"'s parent to parent form

Comment: Hi Goldli Zh I have given the code snippet which i have handled,Please refer ang give your concern

Comment: i have write a custom form , with override WndProc , and output the m.Msg while blinking . there are 127 and 134  .  so i have no idea what's the matter with your code.

Comment: I have handled these three part in wnd proc,And i have found the major problem is because of the following code..Thats why i provide these code.